How to check if IOMMU is enabled in the kernel?
How can I check if IOMMU is enabled in my kernel module?
Is there an API for it?
I've searched in

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/pci-dma.c
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/933069701c1b507825b514317d4edd5d3fd9d417/include/linux/of_iommu.h

but no luck.

I'm just looking for the function, I'll care about the version once I know something exists in some version. There must be a arch-independent function somewhere. dma_alloc_coherent() and similar aren't arch-dependent and still support IOMMU.

There could be multiple IOMMUs on a system, each handling a specific segment of a specific bus. You may want to start from the comments of iommu_present. The include file is this.  At a lower level there's a list of IOMMU devices here but it has static linkage.
